# Springboot application receiving a post request with a body containing an object which contains commas, : and / in it's fields

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application. I receive objects in JSON format containing strings and other nested objects and arrays. The nested objects might contain strings with commas, : and /. I get an error when I pass objects containing commas, : and / in their strings.
I understand those characters are used for parsing JSON objects and therefore when included in the strings they can mess up the conversion. Is there a way to deal with that?

My code:

```
public String setProperties(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) throws JSONException {
        logger.info("->"+ body); 
        System.out.println(body);
        
        String id = body.get("id").toString();
        String name = body.get("name").toString();
        JSONArray props = new JSONArray(body.get("properties").toString());
```

An example of a sent object:

```
{
    "id":4,
    "name":"test",
    "properties":[
        {
            "house":{
                "address":"elm street, 2", ----> this (,) is the responsible part for the error
                "postcode":"000012",
                "area":"001"
            },
            "code":"XXX",
            "lng":"40.3895",
            "created":"2022-04-06:T0:818000200", ---> the (:), also deliver an error
       }
    ]
}
```

The error I get:

```
Expected a ':' after a key at character 43
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:410)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:203)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:344)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:205)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:344)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:125)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:157)
```

Comment: `body.get("properties").toString()` won't give valid json. try removing `toString`. Also share sample value present in `body` variable

Comment: Ok so I have found the problem and a solution to it. I will edit my post as soon i am allowed to